# Python (bs4 + selenium) - Search html data after simulated some actions with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, request

I wrote the following code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.ybpn.de/ihre-parfuemerien/')

search_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("search_input") # Find search form
search_elem.send_keys("80331") # Enter zip code - later based on a .txt of zip codes
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_name("tx_ybpn_storefinder[submit]").submit() # press "submit" button, search
```

Selenium opens the url, search for the "input field", enter a zip code and press submit.

Now I want to search the "new page" (after the action from the code above) for specific data with bs4.

Normally I would use the following code:

```
url = ("https://www.ybpn.de/ihre-parfuemerien/")
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, features="html.parser")
```

**Problem:** When I use the "normal" url it loads the dynamic map without the data I need. The page doesnt create a unique url after I performed the search with selenium. It only adds a specific cHash-value at the end of the url, but when I connect with this url, Im redirected to the "normal page" - there is no url that loads the page with my search results.

**Question:** How can I get a specific url or create a variable after the "search for specific zip code"-action to search with bs4 for the data I need?

I really hope its understandable what I mean! Thank you!

Comment: after submitting, use `driver.current_url` to get the new url and use that

Comment: Do you want to use Selenium along with requests and BeautifulSoup? Why? What is the point?

Comment: the driver.current_url dont work - when I search for the data with bs4 it prints out the regular data without the search action performed . I think its cause there are no url generated that contains information about the search.

Comment: @JaSON - I want to search a dynamic web page. The data I need its loaded when you enter a specific zip code, so I have to simulate the "enter zip code" action first, cause I only need the data from a specific zip code range.

Comment: But why not to use either Selenium or requests+Bs4 for the whole process? I see no sense in mixing these approaches. I guess you're struggling with the X-Y problem

Comment: Sorry man, Im a beginner - I "learned" bs4 in a project ago. I think selenium is for browser automation and bs4 to scrape the data from the webpage. Normally you have a static site (static html data like a table or smth), then you can simply search with bs4 for specific div classes (e.g.). In this case I have a dynamic site - it loads the needed html data when I perform the "search action".

Comment: Yeah that's the problem :) Selenium allows to scrape data as well. Also you can get search results with just python-requests + bs4 or lxml... Note that `driver.get(URL)` and `requests.get(URL)` makes two requests in separate Sessions - they have no relations

Comment: Yeah, you were right too - I dont need selenium here as @Andrej Kesely showed in his answer. I dont know that I can give the zip code directly with the "[searchReq][term]': '80331'}"-line without using selnium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get contacts for specific ZIP code, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.ybpn.de/ihre-parfuemerien/'
data = {'tx_ybpn_storefinder[searchReq][term]': '80331'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
data['tx_ybpn_storefinder[__trustedProperties]'] = soup.select_one('#storefinder [name*=__trustedProperties]')['value']
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(url, data=data).content, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.select('.storefinder__list-item'):
    print(item.select_one('.storefinder-item__title').get_text(strip=True))
    print(item.select_one('.storefinder-item__adress').get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
    print(item.select_one('.storefinder-item__contact').get_text(strip=True))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Parfümerie Brückner
Rindermarkt 1
80331
München
Tel.:+49 89 263181
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parfümerie Brückner
Marienplatz 8
80331
München
Tel.:+49 89 223874
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
City Parfümerie Rathjen
Tal 14
80331
München
Tel.:+49 89 2285222
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Die kleine Theatiner Parfümerie
Theatiner Straße 35
80333
München
Tel.:+49 89 267919
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
City Parfümerie Rathjen
Stachus Passagen Karlsplatz 1. UG
80335
München
Tel.:+49 89 55 4009
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: You really saved my weekend - thank you very much. I dont know that I can give the zip code with "[searchReq][term]': '80331'" without using selenium.

Comment: Could you maybe explain what the "print('-' * 80)" command does? You delivered a perfect solution here for me and I want to understand the code! :)

Comment: @betagurkeDEV `print('-' * 80)` just prints line of 80 characters `'-'` (or character `'-'` is repeated 80 times and then the whole string is printed).

Comment: Yeah, its logic :D now I see, its only the "
separator"

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea based on the accepted answer, which is to get the inner HTML of the whole body.

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://www.ybpn.de/ihre-parfuemerien/')
    
    search_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("search_input") # Find search form
    search_elem.send_keys("80331") # Enter zip code - later based on a .txt of zip codes
    submit_button = driver.find_element_by_name("tx_ybpn_storefinder[submit]").submit() # press "submit" button, search

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.find_element_by_tag_name("body").get_attribute('innerHTML'), features="html.parser")
for item in soup.select('.storefinder__list-item'):
    print(item.select_one('.storefinder-item__title').get_text(strip=True))
    print(item.select_one('.storefinder-item__adress').get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
    print(item.select_one('.storefinder-item__contact').get_text(strip=True))
    print('-' * 80)
```